# Making a branch that is reverted to original repo

Tags: git, github

I have forked a repo, made some edits, and want to make a pull request. However, I have added several features at once in the same branch and not been careful with keeping commits separate. I have also made some of those edits to my master branch (due to inexperience). 
So to make it easier for the original developer, I would like to create several new branches that are completely reverted to the upstream repo and then add my edits carefully (manually) to those before sending the PR.
Can I do that?

thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure -

1. Create a new branch off the required SHA1 commit ID (latest master HEAD, for example), i.e:

   git branch [new_branch_name] [SHA1]
2. Add required changes, commit, test and push. Make sure push is to the new branch, not master.
3. Create a Pull Request.